# Motivation/derivation for Logistic Growth formula?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, logistic-regression

$$P(t) = \frac{c}{1+ae^{-bt}}$$

I see that $ae^{-bt}$ is basically compounding growth formula: $Pe^{rt}$
Not sure what the +1 does.   Includes the original 100% quantity?
What about the reciprocal $\frac{1}{xxxxxx}$ part?

Just wondering how these transforms turn the expoential growth into logistic/S-curve growth.

Comment: Why not just plot this function and be done with it?

Comment: The formula comes from solving the differential equation for logisitc growth, which is a standard equation which, being separable, is easily solved. The formula isn't something which directly pops out of the motivation, but instead pops out of a motivated differential equation. I haven't seen a discussion of the differential equation which *doesn't* discuss its motivation. See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) for a discussion.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the differential equation.  You mean this, right?  https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/6bb558db758be6bfa102f6332a13a606b74912f8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment:

> The formula comes from solving the differential equation for logisitc growth, which is a standard equation which, being separable, is easily solved. The formula isn't something which directly pops out of the motivation, but instead pops out of a motivated differential equation. I haven't seen a discussion of the differential equation which doesn't discuss its motivation. See the Wikipedia article for a discussion. –

Answer (score 0):

For a semi-mechanistic derivation (motivation) of the logistic equation in the case of epidemics, which I believe is what you're asking, you can find it in:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0025556418300853

For a general derivation of the logistic equation from resource model point of view, please find:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yang_Kuang2/publication/254324683_Some_mechanistically_derived_population_models/links/53db0ad80cf2e38c63397ea3.pdf

If you search the article in Google Scholar, you should find a free pdf version somewhere.